# Role permission for bot command

Tags: javascript, permissions, bots, discord.js, roles

Do i have to define something  or something else? I saw that thing with the role permission somewhere online.

`message.member.roles.some is not a function`

```
execute(message, args) {
        if(message.member.roles.some(role => role.name === 'Community Manager')) {
            if (!args.length) return message.channel.send(You didn't pass any command to reload, ${message.author}!);
            const commandName = args[0].toLowerCase();
            const command = message.client.commands.get(commandName)
                || message.client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

            if (!command) return message.channel.send(There is no command with that name or alias `${commandName}`, ${message.author}!);    

            delete require.cache[require.resolve(./${command.name}.js)];

            try {
                const newCommand = require(./${command.name}.js);
                message.client.commands.set(newCommand.name, newCommand);
                message.channel.send(Command `${command.name}` was reloaded!);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                message.channel.send(There was an error while reloading a command `${command.name}`:\n`${error.message}`);
            }
        }else{
            message.channel.send(You don't have the permission to execute that command.);
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they changed it to message.member.roles.cache, also you can use find instead (prob better performance wise, and if not it would be equal, and in that case it still has the pro of better readability),

`messsage.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Community Manager");`

Comment: You were right thanks, but the only problem now is, there is no error anymore, but the  test account with no role can still execute the reload command what shouldnt be possible right? You know why?

Comment: I didn't take a look at the other code when I saw that, why are you reloading a command? Do you have another command to update a command?

As for why the code still runs with test account with no role I'm not sure, can you send the rest of the code that's relevant?

Comment: Ah sorry i forgot, already fixed it, i just used my normal reload command without permission accidently instead of the one with permission